# Python Count values simultaneously in two columns greater than N

Tags: python, pandas, csv, count

Need help counting the occurrence that values in two columns are greater than a value in the same row. For example, if I want to count the number of times each row is greater than 4 and I have columns X & Y such that:
X Y
2 1
5 5
6 3
5 5
The output variable will be 2 since both numbers are greater than 4 in two rows, row 2 and 4.

Thank you

Comment: What exactly is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

```py
In [134]: df.gt(4).all(axis="columns").sum()
Out[134]: 2
```

- check if values are *g*reater *t*han 4; gives True/False's (frame)
- check if we have *all* True's per row; gives True/False's again (series)
- sum to get the count as True -> 1, False -> 0

Comment: Better than my first attempt: `df.query('X > 4 and Y > 4').shape[0]`

Answer (score 0):

What about a comparison like this, in case you're not looking to use any additional packages.
[image: Stack Overflow Helper]

```
x = [2, 5, 6, 5]
y = [1, 5, 3, 5]

counter = 0  # initialize counter variable
min_value = 4  # initialize min_value to compare

for x, y in zip(x, y):
    # print(x, y)
    if x > min_value and y > min_value:
        counter += 1

print("Row Count: " + str(counter))
```

If you are using pandas, then you can use something like this:

```
import pandas as pd

x = [2, 5, 6, 5]
y = [1, 5, 3, 5]

df = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(x, y)), columns=["x", "y"])

min_value = 4  # initialize min_value to compare
counter = df.gt(min_value).all(axis="columns").sum()

print("Row Count: " + str(counter))
```

[image: Stack Overflow Helper 2]

Comment: Thank you for all the help, I have figured this one out.